# android - Select Multiple Objects with checkboxes in custom GridView

Tags: android, gridview, checkbox, multi-select

I'm developing a game and I'm having an Inventory as a GridView. Each grid item is a GameObject which is selected when clicked. The game indicates that the user can either select a single object or combine objects.

What I need is very specific: I want when the user presses the menu button and the optionsMenu appears(with "combine" option), to dynamically draw a checkbox over each grid item, in order to multi-select some items (very much like in Gallery, but with objects instead of images) and then combine them.

I'm using API level 8 so MultiChoiceMode is giving me a hard time.

Also if anyone has a better suggestion on how to implement this functionallity rather than using checkboxes, I would surely be open to it. Thanx in advance

Here's the xml for the grid items:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/grid_item_image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/image_check"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:visibility="invisible" />
```

and the gridView:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/inventoryMsg"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/inventory"/>

<GridView
    android:id="@+id/gridView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_above="@id/inventoryMsg"
    android:columnWidth="90dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:numColumns="3"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp" />
```

and this is the getViewMethod in my CustomAdapter:

```
public View getView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


            View v = convertView;

    if (convertView == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) a.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.griditem, null);
        holder.gameItemCheck = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.image_check);
        v.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
    }
    holder.gameItemCheck.setId(position);
    holder.gameItemCheck.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //dosomestuff
        }
    });

    GameObject gameObject = gameObjectList.get(position);
    ImageView gameItemImageView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_image);


    holder.gameItemCheck.setChecked(Inventory.selected[position]);
    holder.id = position;
    return v;
}

public class ViewHolder {

    public CheckBox gameItemCheck;
    int id;
}
```

**The ways I've tried to change the checkboxes visibilty dynamicaly:**

1)

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keycode, KeyEvent e) {
    switch (keycode) {
    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU:
        openOptionsMenu();
        gameObjectAdapter.holder.gameItemCheck.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        gridView.refreshDrawableState();
        return true;
    }

    return super.onKeyDown(keycode, e);
}
```

2)

```
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            gameObjectAdapter.holder.gameItemCheck.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            gameObjectAdapter.notifyDataSetChange();
    return true;

}
```

Comment: It would be helpful to post some code showing what you have tried that isn't working.

Comment: Currently my code is a bit messy, that's why I didn't post any. I can tell you that I use a custom Adapter extending BaseAdapter and I have a custom Activity class for the inventory. I change the checkboxes visibility inside the onPrepareOptionsMenu. Not sure if I must and how to refresh the gridView after this though.

Comment: Have you tried looping every child in the grid? Do really see what the  your problem is? are you having trouble referencing the childs or?

Comment: If I set the default visibility to true every child gets the checkbox over it. But if I try to change the visibility dynamically it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

## 3 Options

### Adapt from gallery selection

### Method 1:

Just draw a checkbox onto the cell's bitmap when selected. Draw the original when toggle unchecked.
How about using this code:

```
  private Bitmap drawCheck(Bitmap bmp)
  {
   Bitmap bmChecked = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp.getWidth(),     bmp.getHeight(), bmp.getConfig());
   Bitmap check = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(), R.drawable.upcheck);
   Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmChecked);

   canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, null);
   canvas.drawBitmap(check, 0, 0, null); 
   return bmChecked;
  }
```

### Method 2

Use the excellent [code by Mihai Fonoage](http://mihaifonoage.blogspot.com/2009/11/displaying-images-from-sd-card-in.html).

And then:

1. added a selected flag to LoadedImage class,
2. in the onItemClick() function I mark the clicked item as selected
3. in the adapter's getView() use the flag to i.e. set the image background

IT WORKS.

### Method 3: Checkable interface

Have a look at [this example](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Android/UI/ThisdemoillustratestheuseofCHOICEMODEMULTIPLEMODALakaselectionmodeonGridView.htm) -- they use a custom layout class that implements Checkable interface and set a colored background-drawable on checked items.

Comment: I already tried Method 3 but,as I've mentioned before, I'm using API 8 and have problems with MultiChoiceMode. I will try the other 2 Methods though. Thnank you for your answer.